# Shifting the value one position down as the new value is added in tableview in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

friends,I am working with an app where i am populating tableview cells with an array and its getting populated fine,but it is following a standard pattern,the values are  getting added in this positon 
pos0
pos1
pos2
pos3

but what i need is as when the first values is added ,it will obviously add to the first row at pos 0..but when next value is added i want that the new value should come at position 0 and the previous value should move to position 1..

so please help me out..

Thanks &Regards
Ranjit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `datasource` items at a particular index decide where the items come into the tableview. So if your datasource is an array then you can probably add item to it using
`insertObject:atIndex` method. And then you can call the reload data on your tableview.

Comment: Hi praveen ,thans for your reply.but my question is not that,,i am bale to add items but i want it move one positon down as the new item appears..u can think it of like recent items in web history are always shown first so i also want to show recent added value to be shown at the first position

Comment: As @Praveen said you can use [dataSource insertObject:yourObject atIndex:0] and reload table to show recent added value at the top position, provided datasource should be NSMutableArray.

Comment: hi sony i am not getting it...can u please explain with a code snippet,I will be very helpful

Comment: @Ranjit : You need to items to your datasource at index 0 always for it to work the way you want it to.

Comment: @Ranjit try this code http://www.4shared.com/file/96LjOdAV/SampleTable.html   , It will help you..

Comment: Hi sony,I downloaded the example and pretty well understood it..but i have one doubt..i.e my data is coming from a plist in a NSMutable Array.                                                      NSMutableArray *favArray1 = [[NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:plistPath] retain];   but when I try to add it in this way..                                                          [favArray insertObject:[[NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:plistPath] retain] atIndex:0];            the array is not filling up..i am not understanding where i am doing mistake

Comment: Hi sony r u there..please help me out.

Comment: Hi sony i have array of objects                          [[NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:plistPath] retain]..so how to proceed with it with ur code